# Correct Jquery Syntax when loading function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am terrible at Jquery, I reused this code and someone managed to get it working. It needed to do 2 things

1) allow changes after page load and correctly grab sum and totals
2) load pre-loaded form values and calculate them on page load.

I have had to duplicate both functions for 1x .each and 1x .live("keyup" to get the results. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $k = jQuery.noConflict();

  $k.fn.sum = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $k(this).each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($k(this).val());
    });

    return sum;
  }

  $k(function() {


    $k('input[name^=quantity], input[name^=unitprice]').each(function() {
      var quantity = parseFloat($k(this).parent().find('input[name^=quantity]').val());
      var unitprice = parseFloat($k(this).parent().find('input[name^=unitprice]').val());
      $k(this).siblings('input[name^=linetotal]').val(quantity * unitprice);

      var sum = $k('input[name^=linetotal]').sum();

      $k('#subtotal').val(sum);
    });

    $k('input[name^=quantity], input[name^=unitprice]').live("keyup", function() {
      var quantity = parseFloat($k(this).parent().find('input[name^=quantity]').val());
      var unitprice = parseFloat($k(this).parent().find('input[name^=unitprice]').val());
      $k(this).siblings('input[name^=linetotal]').val(quantity * unitprice);

      var sum = $k('input[name^=linetotal]').sum();

      $k('#subtotal').val(sum);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `.trigger('event')`

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    $('input[name^=quantity], input[name^=unitprice]').on('keyup', function()
    {
        var parent = $(this).parent(),
            subtotal = 0,

            quantity = parseFloat(parent.find('input[name^=quantity]').val()),
            unitprice = parseFloat(parent.find('input[name^=unitprice]').val());

        $(this).siblings('input[name^=linetotal]').val(quantity * unitprice);

        $('input[name^=linetotal]').each(function()
        {
            subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        $('#subtotal').val(subtotal);
    })
    .trigger('keyup');
});
```